# ERC-721 Style token on EOS

Tags: tokens, token-standard

Is there any way to create something similar to an ERC-721 token on the EOS network?  I need to create unique tokens.  There seems to be no documentation on this, is it planned for a later date?  This seems like an important feature to add to EOS.

Comment: You could implement this very easily. Seems though that it would consume a lot of RAM and be expensive in EOS as you will need to keep a record for each emited token

Comment: Would it be possible to make the owner of the individual token use their EOS to store it in memory?  Then if they get rid of the token they no longer have to pay the EOS?

Comment: Memory is claimed back when deleting rows. Regarding the payment, probably would make more sense for the owner to pre-emit the number of tokens he wants and then transfer. But is going to cost, depending on ram demand and EOS price, but think for starters a few dollars per token instance

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways, apparently. Here is one.

https://github.com/unicoeos/eosio.nft